# Question regarding trasposes and norms

Tags: matrices

I was pondering my book of linear algebra and I found this solution to question 3.2.2 [here](http://math.hecker.org/2014/04/26/linear-algebra-and-its-applications-exercise-3-2-2/); but the author of the solution follows a path that I am not sure it is correct... when he takes the $||p||^{2}$ norm and expands it I don't understand how from $\lbrack\frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}a\rbrack^{T}\lbrack\frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}a\rbrack$ goes to $\lbrack\frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}\rbrack^2 a^{T}a $. If we put the transpose inside shouldn't the result be $\lbrack a^{T}\lbrack \frac{b^{T}a}{a^{T}a}\rbrack \lbrack\frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}\rbrack a\rbrack$ which doesn't produce the required formula...? Or does it?

Answer (score 0):

For any $c \in \mathbb{R}, u \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ it's true that $[cu]=c[u]$ and $ [cu]^{T}=c[u]^{T}.$

Therefore:

$\\ [cu]^{T}[cu] = c[u]^{T}c[u]\\ =c^{2}u^{T}u$

For your case, take $c=\frac{a^{T}b}{a^{T}a}$

Comment: Well, I don't think that we have a constant here do we? It's a matrix operation... is it not?

Comment: If $a$ and $b$ are vectors, then $[a]^{T}[b]=a \cdot b$. The result of a dot product is a scalar.

Comment: Thinking about it a little more, I see your point. So consider as well $([a]^{T}[b])^{T}=[b]^{T}[a]=[b \cdot a]=[a \cdot b]=[a]^{T}[b]$. Does this help?